# How to delete .jpg file in linux console

Tags: linux, jpeg

By accident I named my image file wrong so I wanted to delete it. So I typed the following in my linux console:

```
rm localapps\logo.jpg
```

But it didn't work.

Then I wrote

```
rm *.jpg
```

then it worked. Simple question. Why did the first not work , even I know that is the way to delete files in linux?

Comment: What is the output for this command: rm localapps\logo.jpg?

Answer (score 2):

We would need the output of the commands you are running. You typically have no output when the command succeeds.

It is also important for you to notice that in linux, the `/` character is used to denote directories, and not `\`, which is actually typically the *[escape](https://linux.die.net/abs-guide/escapingsection.html)* character.

In a terminal is also very important for you to notice in which directory are you working and what is the relative path to the file you want to refer to. You can find this out with the command `pwd` that stands for *print working directory*.

You would see something like

```
your-box:~ blurry$ pwd
/home/blurry
your-box:~ blurry$
```

This said, when you type

```
rm localapps\logo.jpg
```

since `\` is a escape character, this is interpreted as

```
rm localappslogo.jpg
```

this means, it is looking for the file named `localappslogo.jpg` in the current directory (`/home/blurry/localappslogo.jpg`).

I assume that file does not exist, then, it will output something like:

```
rm: localappslogo.jpg: No such file or directory
```

when you type

```
rm *.jpg
```

this code removes any file ending in `.jpg` in the *current directory*. So notice that if you were trying to delete a file that was in the `localapps` folder, you should use instead

```
rm localapps/logo.jpg
```

But this is always assuming that the relative path to your image is `localapps/logo.jpg`.

You can also change directory then delete the file like this,

```
cd localapps
rm logo.jpg
```